# Bidirectional association with one column on the inversed side and multiple on the owning side

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, relationship

I am using Doctrine 2. Let's say we have two entities: *User* and *Bug*. Is it possible to have a bidirectional association with one column on the inversed side (User) and multiple columns on the owning side (Bug)?

[image: Example]

If I define columns in the *Bug* entity like this:

```
/** @Entity */
class Bug {
  /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="associated_bugs") */
  protected $reported_by;

  /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="associated_bugs) */
  protected $assigned_to;
}
```

then I don't know what to write in the *User* entity...

```
/** @Entity */
class User {
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bug", mappedBy="???")
   * @var Bug[]
   **/
  protected $associated_bugs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is something you can not do with mapping. Lets say you would set a list of bugs to `User::associated_bugs`. How would you expect it to store that when calling persist?

You should map the 2 types of bugs separately and next combine them in a method.

```
/** @Entity */
class User {
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bug", mappedBy="reported_by")
   * @var Bug[]
   **/
  protected $reported_bugs;
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bug", mappedBy="assigned_to")
   * @var Bug[]
   **/
  protected $assigned_bugs;

  protected function getAssociatedBugs()
  {
      return array_merge($this->reported_bugs, $this->assigned_bugs);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
/** @Entity */
class User {

  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bug", mappedBy="assigned_to")
   **/
  protected $associated_bugs;


  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bug", mappedBy="reported_by")
   **/
  protected $reported_bugs;

}
```

In Bug entity, you have to add these annotations:

For assigned bugs:

```
@JoinColumn(name="assignee_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
```

and

```
@JoinColumn(name="reporter_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
```

for reported bugs

This should do the job

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right now. But I want to have a *bidirectional* association.

Comment: This -is- bidirectional association

Comment: Yeah, it is. I wanted to say that there are two columns in *User* entity, but I'm asking about a possibility of having only one column in it.